# How to get the window obj the ViewModel is bind with

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have rewriting app into MvvM and having a problem with calling one function from `viewModel`. That function takes as parameter a window it should alter.
I code behind it looks like this:

```
this.utils = new IntroPageUtils(this);
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(this.utils.InitializeWizard), null);
```

where

- this = window which should be altered
- InitializeWizard the method we are calling to make it

In  code behind its quite easy but how how to achieve this in viewModel?

at this moment code behind file is clean:

```
 public partial class IntroPage : Page
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the IntroPage class.
    /// </summary>
    public IntroPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and a viewModel:

```
class IntroPageViewModel: ObservableObject, INavigable
{       
    private ICommand nextButtonCommand;
    private ICommand cancelButtonCommand;
    private IntroPageUtils utils;

    public IntroPageViewModel()
    {
        this.utils = new IntroPageUtils(/*What to put here? */);
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(this.utils.InitializeWizard), null); // There is not such thing as dispatcher here
    }
     /* Rest of a viewModel */   
}
```

I'll be grateful for any samples, guides or tutorials how to overcome this problem.

Comment: That's not MVVM.  Why bother refactoring for MVVM if all you are doing is moving codebehind into a different class?  You should be separating logic from UI concerns.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I received a job to end refactoring this project to mvvm. There was one page already refarctored this way so I was trying to do the same with rest of them. It is my first time with wpf and mvvm so I'll be grateful for any advises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ViewModel is set as Datacontext of a View.

For example :

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel(this);

    }
}
```

In this example, we pass the window in parameter to the view model.
So you can store the reference to the window in the view model.

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region fields

    private MainWindow mainWindow;

    #endregion

    #region properties

    public MainWindow MainWindow
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mainWindow;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public MainViewModel(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This code is building but now I'm getting `TargetInvocationException` I'll investigate this further

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on the answer to a few questions. Could there be more than one instance of the **IntroPageViewModel** in your application? Would these be specific to the window it's view is hosted in? If so (and I assume so), why not pass in your **IntroPage** instance into the constructor of the view model and then use that?

The view model then has a reference to the model it represents, which is perfectly valid I think.

i.e.

View Model:

```
class IntroPageViewModel : ObservableObject, INavigable
{
    private readonly IntroPage _model;

    private readonly IntroPageUtils _introPageUtils;

    public IntroPageViewModel(IntroPage model)
    {
        _model = model;

        _introPageUtils = new IntroPageUtils(Window.GetWindow(_model));
    }
}
```

Wherever you initialise the view model instance:

```
IntroPage introPage = new IntroPage();

IntroPageViewModel viewModel = new IntroPageViewModel(introPage);
```